# MySQL query with Inner Join returning zero rows

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *
FROM Posts
WHERE MATCH (Posts.City) AGAINST ('Lujan')
```

Shows 29 rows. But:

```
SELECT Users.*, Posts.* 
FROM Users 
INNER JOIN Posts ON Users.User = Posts.User 
WHERE MATCH (Posts.City) AGAINST ('Lujan')
```

Got me zero results, while I should get exactly the same results.

Adding explain to the query echoed:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  Posts   fulltext    city_comparator,user_comparator city_comparator 0       1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  Users   eq_ref  user_unique,user_comparator user_unique 62  chusmix.Posts.User  1
```

I have no idea what it means, but also in table users the fulltext index "user_comparator" had a cardinality of 0. While I have registered 10+ users. I also have a Unique index for column Users.User and a primary index for Users.ID.

I changed something and all queries with INNER JOIN stopped working. What can I do to fix this? thanks

Comment: Looks like there aren't any users & posts whose city is Lujan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that there is no row in the Users table which match with the Posts table. If you want to select the rows even if there is no match, use an external join (change the INNER JOIN with a RIGHT JOIN in your case).

Answer (score 1):

Does this return your rows? It's possible there's no corresponding user entry in the Users table for your Posts records.

```
SELECT *
FROM Posts
LEFT JOIN Users ON Users.User = Posts.User
WHERE MATCH (Posts.City) AGAINST ('Lujan')
```