# MySQL inner join returns 0 rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table "ghcn_raw_data" that contains daily weather observations from all of the available weather stations but I'm trying to narrow that down to only the observations from the weather stations in another table "ghcn_stations". The issue I'm having is that when I run the below INNER JOIN it returns 0 rows

```
SELECT ghcn_stations.station_name, ghcn_raw_data.observation_day, ghcn_raw_data.element, ghcn_raw_data.amount 
FROM ghcn_raw_data
INNER JOIN ghcn_stations ON ghcn_raw_data.station_name = ghcn_stations.station_name;
```

If I copy and paste one of the station names that I want into the query like below it works as expected so I know that at least some of the station names exist in ghcn_raw_data, unlike in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073513/mysql-query-with-inner-join-returning-zero-rows)

```
SELECT ghcn_raw_data.observation_day, ghcn_raw_data.element, ghcn_raw_data.amount
FROM ghcn_raw_data
WHERE ghcn_raw_data.station_name = 'AEM00041194'
```

I've also tried using a subquery instead but that got the same results. Both "station_name" columns have the same data type VARCHAR(45)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the values for non-printable symbols other than a space which are not removed during compare. For example, it can be CR/LF, non-breaking space, Tab, etc...

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query